# Get Correct Audit Detail for a particular date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

ok this seems like a long question but I have just put some sample SQL so that you can get a good idea of what I am looking to do.

Basically I have a Stock table with the current price. When the price changes a trigger creates a record in the audit table with the old price and sets the validTo field to the day before. So if I change the price of Apples today from 1:10 to 1:20.. I assume that price 1:10 is for the entire day forward and that the old price of 1:20 was up until midnight yesterday.

Ok all cool... so I thought.  My problem is now that I want to take all my sales and pull out what the price was for that stock item on the sale Date. Note that some prices have not changed like Mango in my example so there is no Audit record to add as the current price is the only price.

I thought I would use a Cross apply on the sales table but having problems.

Here is the sample code... so far..

```
    drop table #CurrentStock
    drop table #AuditTable
    drop table #Sales

    create table #CurrentStock
    (
        StockID     int identity ,
        Stock       varchar(50),
        Quantity    int,
        Price       decimal(5,2),
        Supplier    varchar(50)
    )

    go

    create table #AuditTable
    (
        AuditID int identity,
        StockID int,
        Price   decimal(5,2),
        ValidTo date
    )

    go

    create table #sales
    (
        SaleID  int identity,
        StockID int,
        AmountSold  int,
        DateSold    date
    )

    --Insert 4 stock items and the current price
    insert into #CurrentStock values ('Apple', 200, 1.50, 'Jones');
    insert into #CurrentStock values ('Banana', 300, 1.10, 'Smiths');
    insert into #CurrentStock values ('Oranges', 100, 1.75, 'Ables');
    insert into #CurrentStock values ('Pears', 400, 2.50, 'Jones');
    insert into #CurrentStock values ('Mango', 350, 3.50, 'Jacks'); -- Note this has no audit as the price hasnt changed

    --Insert the Price Changes for the stock
    -- Note the ValidTo field... is up to and including that date so for the first item for apple
    -- the price of 1:10 was valid up to and including 2014-05-01. The next price change of 1.18
    -- would then be valid from 2014-05-02 up to and including 2014-05-07

    insert into #auditTable values (1, 1.10, '2014-05-01');
    insert into #auditTable values (1, 1.18, '2014-05-07');
    insert into #auditTable values (1, 1.22, '2014-05-18');
    insert into #auditTable values (2, 1.11, '2014-05-11');
    insert into #auditTable values (2, 1.14, '2014-05-17');
    insert into #auditTable values (2, 1.16, '2014-05-23');
    insert into #auditTable values (2, 1.12, '2014-05-28');
    insert into #auditTable values (3, 1.86, '2014-05-17');
    insert into #auditTable values (3, 1.92, '2014-05-20');
    insert into #auditTable values (4, 2.62, '2014-05-11');
    insert into #auditTable values (4, 2.67, '2014-05-12');
    insert into #auditTable values (4, 2.92, '2014-05-20');

    -- Create Some Sales

    -- Apples
    insert #sales values ( 1,2,'2014-05-01');   -- price should be 1.10
    insert #sales values ( 1,3,'2014-05-03');   -- price should be 1.18
    insert #sales values ( 1,1,'2014-05-08');   -- price should be 1.22
    insert #sales values ( 1,4,'2014-05-11');   -- price should be 1.22
    insert #sales values ( 1,3,'2014-05-14');   -- price should be 1.22
    insert #sales values ( 1,4,'2014-05-20');   -- price should be current price in stock table

    -- Bananna
    insert #sales values ( 2,2,'2014-05-01');   -- price should be 1.11
    insert #sales values ( 2,5,'2014-05-10');   -- price should be 1.11
    insert #sales values ( 2,2,'2014-05-12');   -- price should be 1.14
    insert #sales values ( 2,4,'2014-05-17');   -- price should be 1.14
    insert #sales values ( 2,2,'2014-05-25');   -- price should be 1.12

    -- Now I want to get the stock that has a price change after the 2014-05-15
    -- If there is no price change like in the case of Mango then we want the current Price
    select * from
    (
        SELECT
            StockId,
            Rank() OVER (Partition By StockId Order By ValidTo Desc) as RowNum,     
            Price,
            ValidTo
        FROM
            #auditTable aud
        WHERE
                ValidTo > '2014-05-15'  -- filter out the records that we dont need

        UNION 

        SELECT
            StockId,
            0 as RowNum,  -- make this Row num 0 so we can group on them        
            Price,
            cast(GETDATE() as DATE)
        FROM 
            #CurrentStock cs
    ) stockList order by StockID,RowNum
```

So all good up to here pulling the prices that have changed. So now the problem is that I want to get all the sales and join to the stock and get the price that the stock was at during the time of the sale... so I need to wrap the above query in a CTE or something that I can do a cross apply on.

I reckoned maybe creating a function that took in a date and stock id and returned the price might be best and use the cross apply on that.. but I don't have the rights to create a function at the moment and need to do it the long way.

Any help greatly appreciated... regards M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
select *
from #sales s
cross apply
(
    select top 1 cs.StockID
        , cs.Stock
        , ISNULL(a.ValidTo, getdate()) as ValidTo
        , ISNULL(a.Price, cs.Price) as Price
    from #CurrentStock cs
    left join #AuditTable a on a.StockID = cs.StockID
    where s.DateSold <= ISNULL(a.ValidTo, getdate())
        and s.StockID = cs.StockID
    order by ISNULL(a.ValidTo, getdate()) 
) x
```

Comment: hi Sean, I cant accept that answer as its to simple and makes me look stupid LOL :-) .. Just pulling it apart but seems to do the trick... I was trying the Top myself but just got into a knot. Let me get back to you and thanks

Comment: LOL. I wouldn't say it makes you look stupid. Sometimes it is hard to see the solution because you are too close to the problem. Hopefully this works for you.

Comment: nice cool and slick solution Sean... yes you are 100% I was so close. I just retro fitted the solution into my more complex application and it works a treat... plus its fast which was my concern as I deal with millions of records.. thanks again.. much appreciated - M

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. It's one option anyway ..

Used your select to get audit filter and saved into a temp table (#TempAudit) ..

```
            select * 
        into #TempAudit    -- saved into temp table called #TempAudit
        from
        (
            SELECT
                StockId,
                Rank() OVER (Partition By StockId Order By ValidTo Desc) as RowNum,     
                Price,
                ValidTo
            FROM
                #auditTable aud
            WHERE
                    ValidTo > '2014-05-15'  -- filter out the records that we dont need

            UNION 

            SELECT
                StockId,
                0 as RowNum,  -- make this Row num 0 so we can group on them        
                Price,
                cast(GETDATE() as DATE)
            FROM 
                #CurrentStock cs
        ) stockList 
         order by StockID,RowNum
```

Using the #TempAudit table ..

Modified:

```
        select *
from #Sales sales
    inner join
    (
        select  ta1.StockId, ta1.RowNum, ta1.Price
        , ta1.ValidTo as ValidDateFromInclusive
        , ISNULL(ta2.ValidTo, '9999-12-31') as ValidDateToExclusive
        from #TempAudit ta1
    left outer join
        #TempAudit ta2
    on ta1.stockId = ta2.stockid and ta1.RowNum - 1 = ta2.rownum
    union all
    select StockId, RowNum+1, Price, '1900-01-01' as ValidDateFromInclusive, ValidTo as ValidDateToExclusive
        from #tempAudit ta
        where rownum = (select max(rownum) from #tempAudit where StockId = ta.StockId)
    ) AuditWithDates
    on sales.StockId = AuditWithDates.StockId 
        and (sales.DateSold >= AuditWithDates.ValidDateFromInclusive and sales.DateSold < AuditWithDates.ValidDateToExclusive)
order by sales.SaleID
```

Comment: hi T-M.. thanks for the help.. very similar to Seans below but using the temp table... just comparing them now... thanks again..

Comment: t-m... thanks again... I went with Seans answer as I didn't need the temp table but thanks for looking at this... regards M

Comment: BTW .. I cannot help but to check the answer as Seans is more elegent for sure. I noticed the Price is different based on your sample data. If I removed the restriction `ValidTo > '2014-05-15' from your Audit query and run Seans and my answer. The `SaleID = 3` has different price `Seans is 1.22` and `mine is 1.18` and `SaleID = 9` where `Seans is 1.14` and `mine is 1.11`. Not sure which answer is correct but you might want to check it out. Please let me know if my script is incorrect for feedback purposes. I have modified my answer due to Audit retrieval.